# Checking irreducibility of a polynomial over a finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, coding-theory

A part of a coding theory course I am doing includes some questions on irreducible polynomials.

I have a question with solution but am worried I have interpreted it incorrectly.

So for $\mathbb F_5$ and polynomials $X^2+2$ and $X^2+X+2$, I want to find whether each is irreducible or not.

The field $\mathbb F_5 = \{0,1,-1,2,-2:5=0\}$.

And I think this is what is confusing me, as I would have used field F_5 = {0,1,2,3,4:5=0}$ and then the question would have not been a problem.
However,

it says $f_1(x)=X^2+2$ so $f_1(0)=2$, $f_1(1)=-2$ and $f_1(-1)=-2$.

Then is says $f_1(-2)=f_1(2)=-1$ but I would have said $f_1(-2)=f_1(2)=X^2+2=4+2=6mod5=1$ **this is the only one I am confused about**

Then for the second polynomial it says $f_2(1)=-1$ and $f_2(-1)=1$.

I will put the rest of results in here so the full answer can be seen:

$f_2(0)=2$(I understood this one, obviously), $f_2(2)=-2$ and $=f_2(-2)$

Thanks!

Comment: The second polynomial is illegible.  It currently reads $X^2+X+"$.  Presumably there should be a scalar term in place of the quotation mark.

Comment: Hint: $-2 \bmod 5 = 3$ and so with $f(x) = x^2+2$, $f(1) = f(-1) = 3 = -2 \bmod 5,$

Comment: Thanks, but why is $f_1(2)=-1$? I would have thought $f_1(2)=6mod5=1$?

Comment: @Bernard: To address your question why negative numbers can be allowed in modular arithmetic, let me ask a question! If I left home at 9 am yesterday and returned after 23 hours, at what time did I return?

Comment: I think everyone got confused with what I was asking, I get and have used them in modular arithmetic before, such as in number theory and codabar numbers etc, but there was one that was confusing me and hence I was wondering if i was understanding them wrong, I have mentioned the one which particularly confused me in the comments above. I don't see why me lecturer hasn't left it equal to 1, and not -1, as 4 would be -1 to me, and 6 equal modular to 1

Answer (score 3):

You can think of $\mathbb{F}_5$ as $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ or you can think of it as $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$.  They are both simpler ways of writing the same thing:

$$\mathbb{F}_5 = \{\left(\begin{matrix}\vdots\\-7\\-2\\3\\8\\\vdots\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}\vdots\\-6\\-1\\4\\9\\\vdots\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}\vdots\\-5\\0\\5\\10\\\vdots\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}\vdots\\-4\\1\\6\\11\\\vdots\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}\vdots\\-3\\2\\7\\12\\\vdots\end{matrix}\right)\}$$

I.e. when working in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$, the following are all equivalent:  $x^2+1\equiv x^2-4\equiv -4x^2+1\equiv 11x^2+6$ because $11\equiv 6\equiv 1\equiv -4\mod{5}$.

As for the question of if $x^2+2$ is irreducible, it may help to view it instead as $x^2+2\equiv x^2-3$.  If it were in fact reducible, then by the fact that it is of order two there would need to be a linear factor that divides it, so that $x^2-3 = (x-a)(x-b)$.  But, that would imply that for $x=a$ you would have $(a-a)(a-b)=a^2-3=0$ which in turn implies that $a^2=3$.  We check to see if $3$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_5$.  By guess and check, we see $0^2=0\neq 3,1^2 = 1\neq 3, 2^2=4\neq 3, 3^2 = 9\equiv 4\neq 3, 4^2 = 16\equiv 1\neq 3$, so $3$ is not a square and therefore the first polynomial is in fact irreducible.

(*this is perhaps the reason they recommended using $-2,-1,0,1,2$... the math is easier.  Note we would have calculated $(-2)^2=4$ instead of $3^2=9\equiv 4$ and $(-1)^2=1$ instead of $4^2=16\equiv 1$, saving some thought*)

---

Although your second polynomial is illegible, given your work, we can assume you mean the second polynomial is $x^2+x+2$.

We can go through the same process.  First we argue that if there *was* a way to reduce the polynomial, since it is degree two it must break into two linear factors, i.e. $x^2+x+2=(x-a)(x-b)$.

Noting again that if $x=a$ that would imply that $a^2+a+2=(a-a)(a-b)=0$, we ask ourselves if any such $a$ exists.

You should have proceeded to calculate $f_2(-2)$ to see if it equaled zero.  $(-2)^2+(-2)+2 = 4 - 2 + 2 = 4\equiv -1$.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer but I have been told I need to use the field with negatives in. I am confused how they are getting the answers for the modular arithmetic still though, with the negatives in the field. Can you please explain how they got the first few that I showed? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews As I mentioned, it makes absolutely no difference which you use.  In $\mathbb{F}_5$ all multiples of 5 are equivalent, all numbers one more than a multiple of 5 are equivalent, etc... so if I were to write $x^2+2$ as $1336x^2 - 43$, I could and it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I held the shift key down whilst pressing 2 resulting in a " but fixed now

Comment: As for how to show that $1336 \equiv 1\mod{5}$, note that $1336 = 1335+1 = 5\cdot k + 1 \equiv 1$ where $k$ is some number I'm too lazy to calculate (all that was important was that 1335 is a multiple of 5, and all multiples of 5 are equivalent to zero).  Do so similarly for all other calculations and simplifications.  Just repeatedly add or subtract multiples of 5 until you are within a comfortable range of zero (either by going down to $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ or by going down to $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$)

Comment: I know I get that - but I <b>have</b> to show my working exactly as above in my question, I would just like to know how they are getting the mods when $f_1(-2)=4+2=6=-1$ I would have thought it would be $-1$ if $f_1(-2)=4$?

Comment: I understand normal mods!! I am just asking about these particular ones, as I was also concerned if my lecturer had made an error

Comment: $f_1(-2) = (-2)^2+2 = 4 + 2 = 6 \equiv 1 \not\equiv -1$  Meanwhile $f_2(-2) = (-2)^2+(-2)+2 = 4 - 2 + 2 = 4\equiv -1$ where $f_1(x)=x^2+2$ and $f_2(x)=x^2+x+2$

Comment: Thanks for being so thorough though with your explanation of mods, there has been times on here where I havent understood the basics so would have been much appreciated and Im sure it will be for people reading this too who are stuck! Just seen your comment above, so is $F_1(-2)=1$ then and not minus 1? That would make more sense..

Answer (score 2):

For any polynomial $p$ over $\Bbb R$, $\color{blue}{a} \in \Bbb R$ is a root of $p$ (that is, $p(\color{blue}{a}) = 0$) iff $X - \color{blue}{a}$ is a factor of $p(X)$, that is, iff there is a polynomial $q$ such that $$p(X) = (X - \color{blue}{a}) q(X).$$

The statement is true if we replace $\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb F_5$. Now, over the latter field we have the advantage: It has only finitely many elements, so to check whether a polynomial $p \in \Bbb F_5[X]$ has any linear factors, it is enough to check whether any of
$p(0), \ldots, p(4)$
is zero (as elements of $\Bbb F_5$!).

Now, a quadratic polynomial (over any field) either is irreducible or not. In the latter case, it factors as a product of two linear factors. So, by the fact above, to check whether a quadratic polynomial $p \in \Bbb F_5[X]$ is irreducible it's enough again to check whether $$p(0), \ldots, p(4)$$ is zero.

In our case, checking the first polynomial, $f_1(X) = X^2 + 2$, gives
\begin{align}
f_1(0) &= (0)^2 + 2 = 0 + 2 = 2\\
f_1(1) &= (1)^2 + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3\\
f_1(2) &= (2)^2 + 2 = 4 + 2 = 1\\
f_1(3) &= (3)^2 + 2 = 4 + 2 = 1\\
f_1(4) &= (4)^2 + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3 .
\end{align}
Note that we've written $f_1(1) = 3$ just as you claimed, and not $f_1(1) = -2$ as in your notes/solution; this is okay, as $3 = -2$ in $\Bbb F_5$ (since $5 = 0$ in this field, we have $-2 = -2 + 0 = -2 + 5 = 3$). Now, none of these values are $0$, so we can conclude that $f_1 \in \Bbb F_5[X]$ is irreducible.

Note that the same argument applies to cubic polynomials but not polynomials of higher degree, as polynomials of degree $\geq 4$ can be reducible but have no linear factors. Over $\Bbb F_5$, for example, $(X^2 + 2) (X^2 + X + 1)$ is reducible, but we showed above that its quadratic factors are irreducible, so it has no linear factors.

Comment: Thanks for this! I now actually get what irreducible is, we want them to equal 0 so they are linear factors! But I am still confused on a few of these mods, I have to use the field with negative values in unfortunately, they want us to use the exact method taught to us, I actually understand how he got all of them apart from $f_1(-2)=-1$,is this an error? I think it should be 1!

Comment: To be clear, the fields are the same and so are the methods. It's simply that the *representation* of the elements (the way we write them down) is different. For example, in place of the equation for $f_1(3)$ above, since $3 = -2$ in our field, we could have written $$f_1(-2) = (-2)^2 + 2 = (-1) + 2 = 1,$$ which gives us the same result as when we used the representation $3$ for the argument above.

Comment: Thanks, I get that they are the same, i just wanted to see if -1 is wrong, as now i understand them all apart from that one, $f_1(2)$. I just dont want to lose marks for anything as they are strict about our methods being exactly the same. I would have have written it as you said and as I said in my comment above, but don't want it to be wrong, although they are both in the field so maybe okay?

Comment: For $f_1(2)$ we have $(2)^2 = -1$, and so $$f_1(2) = (2)^2 + 2 = (-1) + 2 = 1.$$